# Virtual Machine Manager can't be launched after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virt-manager

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I can no more start Virtual Machine Manager. It was running okay when I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and I didn't face any problems but after the upgrade, everything broke. I even installed Windows 10 on it.
Running it from the **Applications Launcher** just don't show anything. I tried running it from the terminal but I always get this error:

```
/usr/bin/virt-manager: 3: exec: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager: not found
```

I tried several times on the terminal but it always throw that same error message, which I don't seem to understand. I thought **KVM** wasn't installed but running **kvm-ok** gives the following message that **KVM** is installed and acceleration can be used:

```
% kvm-ok           
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Also, the Windows 10 image file still exists in `/var/lib/libvirt/images`, plus other directories in the images parent directory.

How can I do to make Virtual Machine Manager run again.

Comment: `apt install --reinstall virt-manager`

Comment: Running `sudo apt install --reinstall virt-manager` gives:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virt-manager.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/virt-manager.prerm: pyclean: not found
 new virt-manager package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/virt-manager_1%3a1.5.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said the error was, in relevant part:

```
pyclean: not found
```

`pyclean` was provided by `python-minimal` package, so you should reinstall that first.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here, found issue was caused by a python library update after installing **awscli**. 
I was forced to restart my system and tried opneing virt-manager and could not open it via GUI, wne to cli and ran:

```
sudo virt-manager
```

returned:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.24.1) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

A Google search found this thread on github: [https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4673.](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4673) They were all discussing about the urllib3  (1.23.1) breaking a bunch of apps including awscli; which I had just installed 2 days prior. At the end of a thread one of the users explained that he back reved the library to version 1.22 and installed awscli again which fixed his problem. Command:

```
pip install --upgrade "urllib3==1.22" awscli awsebcli
```

Welp monkey see it works, monkey follow and it fixed my issue with Virt-Manager, tested awscli and it still works so.

TLDR: if you installed awscli and now Virt-manager broken run

```
pip install --upgrade "urllib3==1.22" awscli awsebcli
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the error message "`exec: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager: not found`" is misleading. Most likely it just can't find the python interpreter. Try running `/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager` because you'll find it is most likely there. You will see an error message akin to "`bash: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager: /usr/bin/python2: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`". Make sure you have python 2 installed. After the upgrade you'll likely have /usr/bin/python2.7 in place. Create a symlink to python2 like so: **`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2`**. After that ./virt-manager should start again just fine.

Comment: Indeed, [Michael Hampton's (accepted) answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469422/117549) covers exactly the situation where a program was not found. It's always useful, when answering, to consider the existing solutions, particularly ones that have been accepted by the asker.